# magnetic nanoparticle

Tags: nanoscience

What magnetic force(I need also an equation) acts on one domain magnetic particle in nonuniform magnetic field? In a case when one domain magnetic particle is magnetic nanoparticle.
Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: A one domain nano-particle can be described as dipole in good approximation, so exactly the forces that act on a magnetic dipole in a non-uniform magnetic field (the torque $\vec \tau = \vec m \times \vec B$ and the force $\vec F = \nabla(\vec m \cdot \vec B)$).

Comment: @SebastianRiese why don't you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

A one domain magnetic nano-particle can be described as a magnetic dipole in good approximation.

This means that the forces acting on such a nano-particle are those acting on a magnetic dipole in a non-uniform magnetic field. Those are

1. A torque
   $$\vec \tau = \vec m \times \vec B, $$
2. A force
   $$\vec F = \nabla (\vec m \cdot \vec B).$$

Here $\vec B$ is the megnetic flux density and $\vec m$ is the magnetic dipole moment of the particle. It is given by
$$ \vec m = \int d^3\vec r \vec M(\vec r) \approx V \vec M, $$
where $\vec M$ is the magnetization (which is assumed approximately constant over the volume) and the integration runs over the volume of the magnet.

Note, that the position dependence of the forces does only come from the orientation of the magnetization axis of the particle and the position dependence of the magnetic field.

In practice, the only reliable method to find the magnetic moment will probably be by fitting measurement data (the free parameter being the scalar $\lvert \vec m \rvert$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sebastian Riese. As I understand B is the magnetic induction (magnetic flux density), and m - what is it, is it the radius vector? Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: @NataliiaTarasiuk I expanded the answer to explain the quantities that occur.

Comment: Sebastian Riese you helped me alot, thank you! Although I have one more question: if I know the volume of nanoparticle, magnetic force F and I need to calculate gradient B, so in that purpose how could be calculated magnetization (material magnetization)? I have magnetite (Fe3O4) nanoparticle. Thank you in advance.